# redirect root to subdirectory wont work apache

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

im learning about mod_rewrite and i have a problem with  this redirection (i dont know why it wont work)...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.net$ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.net$ 
RewriteRule ^/?$ test [L]
```

Well, my test site is on **www.mydomain.net/test** , so when i visit www.mydomain.net or mydomain.net...i want the visitor to see the content of **/test** subdirectory as mydomain.net...

i dont want to change my mydomain.net **to** *mydomain.net/test*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in the root .htaccess (a level above `test` folder):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!test/).*)$ test/$1 [L,NC]
```

`(?!test/)` is a negative lookahead that will route to `test/` only when URI doesn't start with `/test/`.